# Apache Commons CLI DefaultParser NoSuchMethod error

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Options.hasShortOption(Ljava/lang/String;)Z` while I am trying to create an instance of `DefaultParser`.

My code:

```
    Options options = new Options();
    // option for day offset
    options.addOption(new Option("d", "day", true, "Day offset. -d 7 will 
    request for last weeks data"));
    //options.addOption("d", "day", true, "Day offset. -d 7 will request for last weeks data");

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Options.hasShortOption(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.handleShortAndLongOption(DefaultParser.java:491)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.handleToken(DefaultParser.java:243)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.parse(DefaultParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.parse(DefaultParser.java:76)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.parse(DefaultParser.java:60)
    at domain.Main.main(Main.java:60)
```

Line 60 is this:

```
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
```

I was just following official apache documentation - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html.

Yes the library can be found within the jar.

Tried running a couple more combinations, which none of them really worked. On the plus side I got a different error. Kind of.

Stacktrace #2

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Options.getMatchingOptions(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.handleLongOptionWithoutEqual(DefaultParser.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.handleLongOption(DefaultParser.java:384)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.handleToken(DefaultParser.java:239)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.parse(DefaultParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.parse(DefaultParser.java:76)
    at org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.parse(DefaultParser.java:60)
    at domain.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Apache CLI version is 1.4 @mcacorner

Comment: You are victim of classpath pollution

Comment: @rkosegi thanks so much, but i cant find much about classpath polution related to maven.. so, how do i fix it?

Comment: @ZdeněkDavid : start with `mvn dependency:tree` - examine its output and look for duplicate dependencies

Comment: In your main method try to output the result of the following commands: `org.apache.commons.cli.Options.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()` and `org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()`. Both of them should output the same file but are likely not in your setup. You can further investigate your classpath by taking a look at the output of `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`. If you're using maven or gradle `mvn dependency:tree` or `gradle dependencies` will give you more insights.

Comment: @dpr yup, one produces `/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-tools/1.8.2/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar` and the second one `/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/commons-cli-1.4.jar` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is `avro-tools-1.8.2.jar` brings its own version of `commons-cli` which conflicts with the version you want to use.

According to the `META-INF\DEPENDENCIES` file of `avro-tools-1.8.2.jar` it seems to be version 1.2.

Basically you have three options:

1. Use the same version of `commons-cli` that is being used by `avro-tools-1.8.2.jar`. I.e. `commons-cli-1.2`
2. Make sure your version of `commons-cli` is on the classpath before `avro-tools-1.8.2.jar`
3. Re-think the need of using `avro-tools` and remove the dependency if it is not really needed.

If you really need `avro-tools` the first option might be the way to go. The seconds option will probably fix the issue in the first place, but might break functionality of `avro-tools` because of the conflicting version 1.4 of `commons-cli` that will be used. If you don't really need `avro-tools` (not talking about `avro` but the `tools` jar specifically) I'd recommend to remove the `avro-tools` dependency. `avro-tools` doesn't seem to be suited to be pulled as dependency but is more a standalone application. It bundles a bunch of external libraries that all might end up causing version conflicts on your side.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code using apache commons cli 1.4 and it works fine

**EDIT:**

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Option;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Options options = new Options();
        // option for day offset
        options.addOption(new Option("d", "day", true, "Day offset. -d 7 will request for last weeks data"));
        // options.addOption("d", "day", true, "Day offset. -d 7 will request for last
        // weeks data");

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

        CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
        System.out.println(cmd.getParsedOptionValue("day"));


    }
}
```

I've run it with the following args: 
--date 123 
and
-d 123

And it prints 123.

If the error persists copy and paste the code above and check if it works for you.

Comment: The args variable comes as a parameter from main method `public static void main(String[] args)`. Apache CLI version is 1.4

Comment: yes, i know it comes from the main method, but what args are you passing to your example?

Comment: The options object you're creating tells that your program is expecting this: 
--day value
or
-d value

Comment: Tried running these `java -jar kafka-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-export.jar -d=1`, `java -jar kafka-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-export.jar -d 1` and this `java -jar kafka-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-export.jar -d "1"`

Comment: I eventually gave up and just went for another solution.. Still curious why it doesn't work on my machine.